# Linux - sh script - download multiple files from FTP

Tags: linux, ftp, sh

I need script that can download files from ftp via my sh code

I have use `expect` with ftp, but if I do for loop inside code, I got

> wrong # args: should be "for start test next command"
>       while executing "for v in "a b c""

My code

```
/usr/bin/expect << EXCEPT_SCRIPT
set timeout 1
spawn ftp -n ${HOST}
send "user ${USER} ${PASSWD}\n" 
expect "ftp>"
send "bin\n"
expect "ftp>"
send "dir\n"

for v in "${files_to_download[@]}"
do
  ftp_file="${v}.bz2"

  #download file
  echo ${ftp_file}  

  #put code to dl here

done 

 expect "ftp>"
 send "bye\n"
EXCEPT_SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### wget

`expect` can be tricky to work with so I'd prefer to use [GNU Wget](http://wget.addictivecode.org/) as an alternative. The following should work as long as you don’t have any spaces in any of the arguments.

```
for v in "${files_to_download[@]}"
do
  ftp_file="${v}.bz2"
  wget --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWD} ${HOST}/${ftp_file}
done
```

#### Request multiple resources using only one FTP connection

If it’s an issue, you can avoid having to make multiple FTP connections to the server by using *FTP globbing* (wildcard characters), e.g.

```
wget --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWD} "${HOST}/*.bz2"
```

Make sure the URL is quoted so the shell doesn’t expand the wildcard.
You can also use the `-nc, --no-clobber` option to avoid re-downloading files that have already been downloaded.

On the other hand, requesting multiple resources (`wget url2 url2 ...`) *does* result in multiple FTP logins.

*Note: I checked both of the above operations by monitoring Port 21 on my own FTP server with `tcpdump`.*

### ncftp

You may also be interested in [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/). While I haven’t used it in years, I found it – and its `ncftpget` and `ncftpput` utilities – much easier to use for command line scripting than the standard UNIX `ftp` program.

Comment: But with this I will connect/disconnect for every file i dowload. I am worried that ftp provider wont be happy with this.

Comment: @MartinPerry As a server administrator, I wouldn't have thought that would be an issue but I've updated my answer after running a few experiments with wget.